# java string to datetime conversion issue

Tags: java, string, datetime

I can't seem to see the problem with the example code below.  For some reason seems to be ignoring the year and saying the dates are the same, as can be seen in the output below.  I must be missing something simple.

01/28/2006
   01/16/2007
   Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 PDT 2008
   Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 PDT 2008
   done

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    class ExampleProgram {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String d1String = "01/28/2006";
        String d2String = "01/16/2007";
        System.out.println(d1String);
        System.out.println(d2String);
        Date d1=null;
        try {
            d1 = df.parse(d1String);
        } catch (ParseException e) {                
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }           
        Date d2=null;
        try {
            d2 = df.parse(d2String);
        } catch (ParseException e) {                
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println("done");
      }
    }
```

Comment: An April fools joke?  It just seems very contrived that the dates BOTH correspond to April 1.  + 1 year, -12 months == same date.
If your dateformat object is strict (df.setLenient(false)) then it would raise the error for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

should read:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 2):

As Peter mentioned, the meaning of the letters can be found in the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it wasn't giving you what you expected is like Peter said the `SimpleDateFormat` should read `"MM/dd/yyyy"`
The reason that the result is saying that they appear to be equal is because with the format that you've given it `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, `d1String`'s Month is 28. It is taking 28 - 12, adding a year, 16 - 12, adding another year, and the result is 4 (April) and the year is now 2008. Same thing for `d2String`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try declaring your dates as [Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects.

Comment: He did.  The constructor Date(String) is deprecated.  He's using the correct way to convert a String into a Date.