# Android Convert String to Date

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am new to android deveolpment. I want to convert the `String` "Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00:00 CST" to a `Date`, and I also want to add this date to personal calendar.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this with Java SDK or C++ NDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date d= new SimpleDateFormat("Yourdateformathere").parse("yourstringhere");
```

Answer (score 1):

This question looks somewhat similar to: [java string to datetime conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746259/java-string-to-datetime-conversion-issue)

```
String d1String = "Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00:00 CST";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
Date d1 = df.parse(d1String);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    String time1 = "Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:00:00 CST";
    String str="";
    Date date;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z").parse(time1);
         str = new SimpleDateFormat("YOUR REQUIRED FORMATE").format(date);

        System.out.println("output DATE== "+str);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```